# Tomcat Server running springboot application apruptly closes connection to smtp server

Tags: linux, smtp, tomcat

I have a tomcat server running a spring boot application on a host using CentOS 8 that connects to a mail client using SMTP. Problem is it abruptly closes connection before TLS handshake occurs with a STARTTLS option. It works OK with other nodes running CentOS 7 and Oracle linux server. The problem cannot be with the application otherwise it would not work on any nodes. I checked using Wireshark to see that it was our application node terminating the connection. Here is the TCP communication transcript I recorded using tcpdump.

```
220 mta1.***.local ESMTP Postfix
EHLO ****
250-mta1.***.local
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 69730304
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

And nothing after that. Connection termination was abrupt, no timeout or anything like that. I also checked for server.xml file for any settings there was no mention of mail or smtp in any way.

I tried the same using openssl and it works, successfully starting TLS over smtp connection so it is not the issue with server not supporting the option either. Does  anyone have any idea why this might have happened?

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.****.gov.**:587 -starttls smtp
```

My catalina.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
cygwin=false
darwin=false
os400=false
hpux=false
case "`uname`" in
CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
Darwin*) darwin=true;;
OS400*) os400=true;;
HP-UX*) hpux=true;;
esac

# resolve links - $0 may be a softlink
PRG="$0"

while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
  else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`/"$link"
  fi
done

# Get standard environment variables
PRGDIR=`dirname "$PRG"`

# Only set CATALINA_HOME if not already set
[ -z "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && CATALINA_HOME=`cd "$PRGDIR/.." >/dev/null; pwd`

# Copy CATALINA_BASE from CATALINA_HOME if not already set
[ -z "$CATALINA_BASE" ] && CATALINA_BASE="$CATALINA_HOME"

# Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup,
# but allow them to be specified in setenv.sh, in rare case when it is needed.
CLASSPATH=

if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
elif [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"
fi

# For Cygwin, ensure paths are in UNIX format before anything is touched
if $cygwin; then
  [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
  [ -n "$JRE_HOME" ] && JRE_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JRE_HOME"`
  [ -n "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && CATALINA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$CATALINA_HOME"`
  [ -n "$CATALINA_BASE" ] && CATALINA_BASE=`cygpath --unix "$CATALINA_BASE"`
  [ -n "$CLASSPATH" ] && CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --unix "$CLASSPATH"`
fi

# Ensure that neither CATALINA_HOME nor CATALINA_BASE contains a colon
# as this is used as the separator in the classpath and Java provides no
# mechanism for escaping if the same character appears in the path.
case $CATALINA_HOME in
  *:*) echo "Using CATALINA_HOME:   $CATALINA_HOME";
       echo "Unable to start as CATALINA_HOME contains a colon (:) character";
       exit 1;
esac
case $CATALINA_BASE in
  *:*) echo "Using CATALINA_BASE:   $CATALINA_BASE";
       echo "Unable to start as CATALINA_BASE contains a colon (:) character";
       exit 1;
esac

# For OS400
if $os400; then
  # Set job priority to standard for interactive (interactive - 6) by using
  # the interactive priority - 6, the helper threads that respond to requests
  # will be running at the same priority as interactive jobs.
  COMMAND='chgjob job('$JOBNAME') runpty(6)'
  system $COMMAND

  # Enable multi threading
  export QIBM_MULTI_THREADED=Y
fi

# Get standard Java environment variables
if $os400; then
  # -r will Only work on the os400 if the files are:
  # 1. owned by the user
  # 2. owned by the PRIMARY group of the user
  # this will not work if the user belongs in secondary groups
  . "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh
else
  if [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh ]; then
    . "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh
  else
    echo "Cannot find $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setclasspath.sh"
    echo "This file is needed to run this program"
    exit 1
  fi
fi

# Add on extra jar files to CLASSPATH
if [ ! -z "$CLASSPATH" ] ; then
  CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH":
fi
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH""$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/bootstrap.jar

if [ -z "$CATALINA_OUT" ] ; then
  CATALINA_OUT=/home/******/logs/catalinalogs/catalina.out
fi

if [ -z "$CATALINA_TMPDIR" ] ; then
  # Define the java.io.tmpdir to use for Catalina
  CATALINA_TMPDIR="$CATALINA_BASE"/temp
fi

# Add tomcat-juli.jar to classpath
# tomcat-juli.jar can be over-ridden per instance
if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" ] ; then
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_BASE/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
else
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_HOME/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
fi

# Bugzilla 37848: When no TTY is available, don't output to console
have_tty=0
if [ -t 0 ]; then
    have_tty=1
fi

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin; then
  JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$JAVA_HOME"`
  JRE_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$JRE_HOME"`
  CATALINA_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_HOME"`
  CATALINA_BASE=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_BASE"`
  CATALINA_TMPDIR=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_TMPDIR"`
  CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --windows "$CLASSPATH"`
  [ -n "$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" ] && JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS=`cygpath --path --windows "$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS"`
fi

if [ -z "$JSSE_OPTS" ] ; then
  JSSE_OPTS="-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048"
fi
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $JSSE_OPTS"

# Register custom URL handlers
# Do this here so custom URL handles (specifically 'war:...') can be used in the security policy
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources"

# Set juli LogManager config file if it is present and an override has not been issued
if [ -z "$LOGGING_CONFIG" ]; then
  if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/logging.properties ]; then
    LOGGING_CONFIG="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties"
  else
    # Bugzilla 45585
    LOGGING_CONFIG="-Dnop"
  fi
fi

if [ -z "$LOGGING_MANAGER" ]; then
  LOGGING_MANAGER="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
fi

# Set UMASK unless it has been overridden
if [ -z "$UMASK" ]; then
    UMASK="0027"
fi
umask $UMASK

# Java 9 no longer supports the java.endorsed.dirs
# system property. Only try to use it if
# JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS was explicitly set
# or CATALINA_HOME/endorsed exists.
ENDORSED_PROP=ignore.endorsed.dirs
if [ -n "$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" ]; then
    ENDORSED_PROP=java.endorsed.dirs
fi
if [ -d "$CATALINA_HOME/endorsed" ]; then
    ENDORSED_PROP=java.endorsed.dirs
fi

# Make the umask available when using the org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=`umask`"

if [ -z "$USE_NOHUP" ]; then
    if $hpux; then
        USE_NOHUP="true"
    else
        USE_NOHUP="false"
    fi
fi
unset _NOHUP
if [ "$USE_NOHUP" = "true" ]; then
    _NOHUP="nohup"
fi

# Add the JAVA 9 specific start-up parameters required by Tomcat
JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="$JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="$JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED"
JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="$JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED"
export JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS

# ----- Execute The Requested Command -----------------------------------------

# Bugzilla 37848: only output this if we have a TTY
if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Using CATALINA_BASE:   $CATALINA_BASE"
  echo "Using CATALINA_HOME:   $CATALINA_HOME"
  echo "Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: $CATALINA_TMPDIR"
  if [ "$1" = "debug" ] ; then
    echo "Using JAVA_HOME:       $JAVA_HOME"
  else
    echo "Using JRE_HOME:        $JRE_HOME"
  fi
  echo "Using CLASSPATH:       $CLASSPATH"
  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    echo "Using CATALINA_PID:    $CATALINA_PID"
  fi
fi

if [ "$1" = "jpda" ] ; then
  if [ -z "$JPDA_TRANSPORT" ]; then
    JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_ADDRESS" ]; then
    JPDA_ADDRESS="localhost:8000"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_SUSPEND" ]; then
    JPDA_SUSPEND="n"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_OPTS" ]; then
    JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"
  fi
  CATALINA_OPTS="$JPDA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS"
  shift
fi

# TODO: Bugzilla 63815
# This doesn't currently work (and can't be made to work) if values used in
# CATALINA_OPTS and/or JAVA_OPTS require quoting. See:
# https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8234808
if [ "$1" = "debug" ] ; then
  if $os400; then
    echo "Debug command not available on OS400"
    exit 1
  else
    shift
    if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
      if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "Using Security Manager"
      fi
      shift
      exec "$_RUNJDB" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
        -D$ENDORSED_PROP="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" \
        -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
        -sourcepath "$CATALINA_HOME"/../../java \
        -Djava.security.manager \
        -Djava.security.policy=="$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/catalina.policy \
        -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
        -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
        -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
        org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
    else
      exec "$_RUNJDB" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
        -D$ENDORSED_PROP="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" \
        -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
        -sourcepath "$CATALINA_HOME"/../../java \
        -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
        -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
        -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
        org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
    fi
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "run" ]; then

  shift
  if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
    if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Using Security Manager"
    fi
    shift
    eval exec "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER "$JAVA_OPTS" "$CATALINA_OPTS" \
      -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \
      -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
      -Djava.security.manager \
      -Djava.security.policy=="\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\"" \
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
  else
    eval exec "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER "$JAVA_OPTS" "$CATALINA_OPTS" \
      -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \
      -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "start" ] ; then

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      if [ -s "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        echo "Existing PID file found during start."
        if [ -r "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
          PID=`cat "$CATALINA_PID"`
          ps -p $PID >/dev/null 2>&1
          if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
            echo "Tomcat appears to still be running with PID $PID. Start aborted."
            echo "If the following process is not a Tomcat process, remove the PID file and try again:"
            ps -f -p $PID
            exit 1
          else
            echo "Removing/clearing stale PID file."
            rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
            if [ $? != 0 ]; then
              if [ -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                cat /dev/null > "$CATALINA_PID"
              else
                echo "Unable to remove or clear stale PID file. Start aborted."
                exit 1
              fi
            fi
          fi
        else
          echo "Unable to read PID file. Start aborted."
          exit 1
        fi
      else
        rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
          if [ ! -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
            echo "Unable to remove or write to empty PID file. Start aborted."
            exit 1
          fi
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi

  shift
  touch "$CATALINA_OUT"
  if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
    if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Using Security Manager"
    fi
    shift
    eval $_NOHUP "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER "$JAVA_OPTS" "$CATALINA_OPTS" \
      -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \
      -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
      -Djava.security.manager \
      -Djava.security.policy=="\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\"" \
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"

  else
    eval $_NOHUP "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER "$JAVA_OPTS" "$CATALINA_OPTS" \
      -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \
      -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"

  fi

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    echo $! > "$CATALINA_PID"
  fi

  echo "Tomcat started."

elif [ "$1" = "stop" ] ; then

  shift

  SLEEP=5
  if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
    echo $1 | grep "[^0-9]" >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
      SLEEP=$1
      shift
    fi
  fi

  FORCE=0
  if [ "$1" = "-force" ]; then
    shift
    FORCE=1
  fi

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      if [ -s "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        kill -0 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
          echo "PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission to stop the process. Stop aborted."
          exit 1
        fi
      else
        echo "PID file is empty and has been ignored."
      fi
    else
      echo "\$CATALINA_PID was set but the specified file does not exist. Is Tomcat running? Stop aborted."
      exit 1
    fi
  fi

  eval "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER "$JAVA_OPTS" \
    -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \
    -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
    -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
    -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
    -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
    org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" stop

  # stop failed. Shutdown port disabled? Try a normal kill.
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      echo "The stop command failed. Attempting to signal the process to stop through OS signal."
      kill -15 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi
  fi

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      while [ $SLEEP -ge 0 ]; do
        kill -0 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
          rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
          if [ $? != 0 ]; then
            if [ -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
              cat /dev/null > "$CATALINA_PID"
              # If Tomcat has stopped don't try and force a stop with an empty PID file
              FORCE=0
            else
              echo "The PID file could not be removed or cleared."
            fi
          fi
          echo "Tomcat stopped."
          break
        fi
        if [ $SLEEP -gt 0 ]; then
          sleep 1
        fi
        if [ $SLEEP -eq 0 ]; then
          echo "Tomcat did not stop in time."
          if [ $FORCE -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "PID file was not removed."
          fi
          echo "To aid diagnostics a thread dump has been written to standard out."
          kill -3 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"`
        fi
        SLEEP=`expr $SLEEP - 1 `
      done
    fi
  fi

  KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL=5
  if [ $FORCE -eq 1 ]; then
    if [ -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      echo "Kill failed: \$CATALINA_PID not set"
    else
      if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        PID=`cat "$CATALINA_PID"`
        echo "Killing Tomcat with the PID: $PID"
        kill -9 $PID
        while [ $KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL -ge 0 ]; do
            kill -0 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
            if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
                rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
                if [ $? != 0 ]; then
                    if [ -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                        cat /dev/null > "$CATALINA_PID"
                    else
                        echo "The PID file could not be removed."
                    fi
                fi
                echo "The Tomcat process has been killed."
                break
            fi
            if [ $KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL -gt 0 ]; then
                sleep 1
            fi
            KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL=`expr $KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL - 1 `
        done
        if [ $KILL_SLEEP_INTERVAL -lt 0 ]; then
            echo "Tomcat has not been killed completely yet. The process might be waiting on some system call or might be UNINTERRUPTIBLE."
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "configtest" ] ; then

    eval "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER "$JAVA_OPTS" \
      -D$ENDORSED_PROP="\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\"" \
      -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
      -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
      -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap configtest
    result=$?
    if [ $result -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Configuration error detected!"
    fi
    exit $result

elif [ "$1" = "version" ] ; then

    "$_RUNJAVA"   \
      -classpath "$CATALINA_HOME/lib/catalina.jar" \
      org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo

else

  echo "Usage: catalina.sh ( commands ... )"
  echo "commands:"
  if $os400; then
    echo "  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger (not available on OS400)"
    echo "  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager (not available on OS400)"
  else
    echo "  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger"
    echo "  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager"
  fi
  echo "  jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger"
  echo "  run               Start Catalina in the current window"
  echo "  run -security     Start in the current window with security manager"
  echo "  start             Start Catalina in a separate window"
  echo "  start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager"
  echo "  stop              Stop Catalina, waiting up to 5 seconds for the process to end"
  echo "  stop n            Stop Catalina, waiting up to n seconds for the process to end"
  echo "  stop -force       Stop Catalina, wait up to 5 seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running"
  echo "  stop n -force     Stop Catalina, wait up to n seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running"
  echo "  configtest        Run a basic syntax check on server.xml - check exit code for result"
  echo "  version           What version of tomcat are you running?"
  echo "Note: Waiting for the process to end and use of the -force option require that \$CATALINA_PID is defined"
  exit 1

fi
```

My setenv.sh file

```
# -Xms/Xmx
#   Xms Sets the initial size of the Heap
#   Xmx sets the Maximum size of the Heap.
#  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087153/what-happens-when-we-set-xmx-and-xms-equal-size
#  http://crunchify.com/jvm-tuning-heapsize-stacksize-garbage-collection-fundamental/
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m"
```

Comment: Anyone answer this?